Using DBSCAN with multiple numpy array datasets, sklearn labels
I am using DBSCAN to analyse multiple sets of labels generated using sklearn. I am currently having difficulty combining the datasets in the right format for analysis, I have used multiple methods of appending and extending the sets as both arrays and lists and I am currently having difficulty with dimensional errors.
Advice would be appreciated for the best method of combining the datasets, or if it there is a way to analyse multiple datasets concurrently using DBSCAN would be appreciated.

It's hard to help without info on the things you are trying to combine.  For example wbat dimensions and what errors?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
